# getting required json formatting

Tags: php, kohana-3, json

Hi friends i'm getting json from server (using kohana framework 3.0) like this....

```
 {
        "aaData": [
            {
                "regNo": "1",
                "regDate": "2025-05-12",
                "patientName": "Ratna",
                "address": "saasgasgasga",
                "city": "Hyderabad",
                "phno": "2147483647",
                "mrgStatus": "single",
                "religion": "1",
                "gender": "male",
                "fathername": "Yohan",
                "status": "2",
                "age": "25"
            }
        ]
    }
```

but i want below format

```
{
        "aaData": [
            [
               "1",
               "2025-05-12",
               "Ratna",
               "saasgasgasga",
               "Hyderabad",
                "2147483647",
                "single",
                "1",
                "male",
                "Yohan",
                "2",
                "25"
            ]
        ]
    }
```

kohana controller is

```
public function action_index()
    {
         $table = new Model_patientdetails();
         $log =$table ->get_all();
         $output = array("aaData" => $log);
         $this->auto_render=false;
         echo json_encode($output);
    }
```

please suggest me how to get required json format

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **array_values()** for get the values only

```
public function action_index()
{
     $table = new Model_patientdetails();
     $log =$tab ->get_all();
     foreach($log as &$l)
     {
        $l = array_values($l)
     }
     $output = array("aaData" => $log);
     $this->auto_render=false;
     echo json_encode($output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found `$log1` variable at your code, so I think it was `$log`.

You can do it in this way:

```
public function action_index()
    {
         $table = new Model_patientdetails();
         $log = $tab->get_all();
         $output = array("aaData" => array_values($log));
         $this->auto_render=false;
         echo json_encode($output);
    }
```